# Is there a "Meta-API" for Zapier?

Tags: api, zapier

While Zapier is very powerful at putting glue between various APIs, I stumbled upon the use case of creating Zaps programmatically, which would offer even more flexibility.

I did some investigation and it appears that Zapier, to this date, does not provide a public API for doing so. Is there any workaround for that ?

Answer (score 3):

Not currently. Creating a zap involves a lot of UI steps (6 or 7) - many of which depend on choices made in each previous step, so trying to do all that through a remote script might be difficult and messy. Maybe share some ideas on your specific use-case: why do you need to create a zap programmatically?

Keep in mind you can also create private apps on Zapier so if there is specific functionality you need to use with Zapier you can do that without exposing it to the world.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use Zapier as a part of my stack for push notifications. As Zap parameters, in production, will vary from one customer to another, you do imagine that preparing each instance of them manually is beyond fastidious. Sorry if this is somehow unclear, there is a NDA around the topic.

Comment: I understand. One other thing you could do to speed up creation of zaps is to create zap templates (by sharing individual zaps) and then linking to them directly, IE: `https://zapier.com/app/editor/634435`. This at least skips that first step of finding both apps.

Answer (score 1):

The year 2017 Zapier [introduced](https://zapier.com/blog/get-your-favorite-app-on-zapier/) their [Command Line Interface](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli), which makes possible building your app programatically via JavaScript.

You can take a look at the [Example Apps](https://github.com/zapier?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=zapier-platform-example-app&type=&language=) as well as the [CLI-docs](https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform-cli/cli.html).